# how to customized hr,month,year in python date time module?

Tags: python, datetime

How can i customize hrs,days,months of date time module in python?
day of 5 hrs only, a month of 20 days only, and a year of 10 months only.
using date time module.

Comment: You cannot.  `datetime` implements the "proleptic Gregorian calendar" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar) and makes no provisions for changing anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @TimPeters . This just doesn't fit in what datetime does.

For your needs, I would be inclined to start my own class from scratch, as that is pretty far from datetime.

That said...you *could* look into monkeypatching datetime...but I would recommend against it. It's a pretty complex beast, and changing something as fundamental as the number of hours in a day will blow away unknown assumptions within the code, and would certainly turn its unit tests upside down.

Build your own from scratch is my advice.

Comment: datetime can't be monkeypatched, as it's a built-in type with no `__dict__` namespace.